# Command for launch a new terminal, or a new tab if exists

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have a keyboard shortcut that is mapped to running the command `gnome-terminal` (I'm on Fedora 27).

I wish that this key, would open a new terminal if no terminal is open, but open a new tab on the existing terminal window if a terminal window is already open.

What would be the command to do that?

Comment: What if there's more than 1 gnome-terminal already open?

Comment: Well open in one of them, doesn't really matter... whatever is easier to implement in that case would suffice

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure entirely for Fedora but on CentOS the command to open a new tabbed terminal window is `Ctrl+Shift+t` when the terminal window is selected! as for opening a new window, you will have to bind that as you have done!

Comment: I am looking for a shell command that will start a terimnal if no terminals are open, and if there are it will open a new tab on the existing terminal. It should be a command not a keyboard stroke

Comment: oh you will want to write a small bash script to do that for you and then bind that to a key of your choice. I am unsure of how you will go about that, i guess capturing mouse events to see if you have the terminal selected and if so, create new tab, else just open a window. it seems like a lot of work for such a small task

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a way to detect a running terminal and send keys to that window. There are several of them.
I'd suggest you  xdotool ( `sudo dnf install xdotool` for Fedora )

```
#!/bin/sh
EW=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --classname Gnome-terminal|head -1)

if [[ -z  $EW ]]
then
 gnome-terminal &
else
 xdotool windowactivate --sync  $EW
 xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+shift+t
fi
```

Put this code above in, say, ~/bin/gterm file then make `chmod 0755 ~/bin/gterm`

Afterwards gterm command is ready. Furthermore you can bind it to a shortcut.

Comment: When I try to do that, I get the following error `not found
XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1)` (trying it on Ubuntu instead of Fedora)

Answer (score 0):

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "echo hello"
end tell'
```

This opens a new terminal and executes the command "echo hello" inside it.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/308460/253065)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking as you said in [the comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407921/command-for-launch-a-new-terminal-or-a-new-tab-if-exists#comment730295_407930)

```
gnome-terminal
```

[image]

If you run the code it will open another `terminal` from a existing `terminal`